# sum of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{1+3\cdot(-1)^n}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Not sure how to evaluate this. I'm pretty sure I should examine the difference between even and odd indicies.

So it's jumping between:

$(1/4)^n$ when $n$ is even

and $(-1/2)^n$ when $n$ is odd

But, I don't think it's as simple as just plugging in the two values in the geometric series function with $1/4$ and $(-1/2)$. Where do I go from this point?

Comment: Work out the sum of the even terms, and the sum of the odd terms.  Then add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just expand Henry's comment, because I had the same thought.

For even $n$,
the sum is

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/4^{2n}
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/16^{n}\\
&= 1/(1-1/16)\\
&= 16/15\\
\end{align}
$

For odd $n$,
the sum is

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/(-2)^{2n+1}
&= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/2^{2n+1}\\
&= -(1/2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/2^{2n}\\
&= -(1/2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 1/4^{n}\\
&= -(1/2)/(1-1/4)\\
&= -(1/2)(4/3)\\
&=-2/3\\
\end{align}
$

Adding, the overall sum is
$16/15-2/3 = (16-2*5)/15 = 6/15 = 2/5$.